# Docker Wordpress connection to the database server on the localhost

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, localhost, database-connection

I run [docker wordpress image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) with command

```
docker run --name  test-wordpress -p 8081:80 -d wordpress
```

MySQL 8 is on localhost on Windows 10. Database credentials are valid.

In wordpress setup I use this configuration

- Database name: wordpress (not exist yet)
- Username: root
- Password: ***
- Database host: **localhost**  || **127.0.0.1** || **host.docker.internal**

I get error

**Error establishing a database connection**

What is correct database host?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, docker will attach your new container to a bridged network. This means that addresses such as: `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` only refers to the container itself. Not the host machine.

The easy was to solve this, is to wrap the MySQL database in a container of it's own. This way your containers can address eachother without issues.

### Connect to MySQL database on the host

If you really want to connect the service in the container with a service on the host, you will need to connect the container to the appropriate network.

First, you will need to create a network. Assuming that your local machine has a fixed IP of `192.168.0.1`, you should be able to do this with:

```sh
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 --gateway 192.168.0.1 dockernet
```

You can then:

```sh
docker run --name  test-wordpress --net=dockernet -p 8081:80 -d wordpress
```

And you should then be able to refer to the host from inside the container by the IP: `192.168.0.1`.

### Create stack with wordpress and MySQL

The better alternative here though, is to create an application stack definition with docker-compose, that includes both the database and the wordpress application.

You can create a `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

**`docker-compose.yml`**

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

And the start the stack with this:

```sh
docker-compose up
```

Then visit: http://localhost:8000

Notice that the database data will be stored in the docker managed volume called `db_data`.

Details on installing docker-compose can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

### Start both containers with just `docker run`

The same can be achieved with just `docker run`, like this:

```sh
docker volume create db_data

docker network create mysqlnet

docker run --name test-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=somewordpress -e MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress -e MYSQL_USER=wordpress -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress -v db_data:/var/lib/mysql --net=mysqlnet -d mysql:5.7

docker run --name test-wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=test-mysql:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress --net=mysqlnet -p 8081:80 -d wordpress:latest
```

You can change the mapping of the mysql datafiles to a local directory instead, and just ommit the `docker volume create` statement.

Comment: Thank you very much for very detail and good answer. You help me a lot and save my time.

Comment: Thanks int - what solution did you go with? I think I will add something to the answer. You can also start the wordpress container with the "host network mode" - which I also believe will solve the problem.

Comment: Having both the docker-compose style and the plain ol' CLI commands was great, and helped solidify some concepts around networks and volumes! Thanks! Note: I think specifying a volume isn't technically necessary, though it would be silly to make a DB container without one.

Comment: Fantastic answer

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is incomplete and inaccurate.  You can very easily connect to MySQL running in host machine with wordpress running inside container by providing `--network=host` option during `docker run`.

**Issue With Wordpress:**
The only caveat is `wordpress` can't connect with `MySQL` with default setup.
In Ubuntu systems running MySQL 5.7 (and later versions), any MySQL user is set to authenticate using the `auth_socket plugin` by default rather than with a `password`. This allows for some greater security and usability in many cases, but it can also complicate things when you need to allow an external incompatible program like `wordpress` to access the user.

In order to use a `password` to connect to MySQL as user, you will need to switch its authentication method from `auth_socket` to `mysql_native_password`.

**Solution:**
Create a dedicated mysql user for wordpress database in legacy `mysql_native_password` mode.

```sql
$> sudo mysql
mysql> CREATE USER 'wpuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'wp_password';
mysql> CREATE DATABASE wordpress_db CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON wordpress_db.* TO 'wpuser'@'localhost';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Run Wordpress container:
`docker run --rm --name my_wordpress --network=host -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wpuser -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wp_password -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress_db -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 wordpress`

Comment: On which port is this supposed to run? When I browse to 127.0.0.1 it's not showing up

Comment: by the default the port is 80, please check wordpress container logs to check if your server is running

Answer (score 1):

Found a great article explaining [How to setup Wordpress using Docker](https://medium.com/@habibridho/how-to-easily-setup-wordpress-using-docker-a798081dc577).

The issue is MySQL container is not accessible from the wordpress container, so to fix this we will have to create docker network and connect both the containers.

Lets create a docker network -

```
> docker network create --attachable wordpress-network
```

Now attach both the containers with following command -

```
> docker network connect wordpress-network mysql-container
> docker network connect wordpress-network wordpress-container
```

Now open the wordpress in browser and set **mysql-container** as Database Host

Comment: I believe the question was how to connect to an existing database running on the host, not docker container